# IMSI on the Windows Phone 7 platform?

Tags: windows-phone-7, native-code

Is there a way to retrieve IMSI on the Windows Phone 7 platform?

Regards,
Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires you to use native access, which is not officially supported and will not get your app approved in the Marketplace. I know that with the Dell Venue Pro I managed to access that data [through AT commands](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/dell-venue-pro-commands-while).

As long as you can get the phone in Modem mode, you can run AT+CIMI to get the IMSI value.

Comment: Thanks, however, the app I'm developing needs to get to the Marketplace.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In short, No. There is no way to get any information on SIM card or phone itself except Mobile operator name

Comment: Ok, that sucks. It is available on all other mobile dev platforms and is important from an app point of view to ensure that the link between the SIM and the user.

Answer (score 0):

Under 'settings - about' I find SIM-ID number, is this information available via a 'standard' API like Mobile Operator name?

If available, as a work-around for WP7 maybe link SIM-ID to IMSI on the 'back-end'.

What about Windows Phone 8 and 'secure NFC' - standard APIs to retrieve IMSI should be available then?

KR,
Ahmad